# What are the units of the QGIS roughness tool results?

Tags: qgis, units

When I estimate Roughness, using QGIS [Raster > Analysis > DEM (Terrain models)], what is the unit of the values I get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pressing the Help button takes you to [the tool's documentation on the GDAL homepage:](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html)

> roughness
>
> This command outputs a single-band raster with values computed from the elevation. Roughness is the largest inter-cell difference of a central pixel and its surrounding cell, as defined in Wilson et al (2007, Marine Geodesy 30:3-35).

Sounds like the units are same as the input raster value units.